# Calculate Average True Range directly with Dataframe

Tags: pandas

I wonder if there is a simple and direct way to calculate [ATR](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/a/atr.asp) from DataFrame object. I am stuck in the max() part. This is what I am trying to do:

```
df['atr']=max( (df['High']-df['Low']), (df['High']-df['Close'].shift()).abs(), (df['Low']-df['close'].shift()).abs() )
```

The above code gives this error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

I understand that to use max() in this context is not appropriate for the dataframe object. But if it works this would be rather elegant and simple. Just wonder if there are built in functions within dataframe object to achieve this.

Comment: A quick searched on google gave me this: https://www.learnpythonwithrune.org/calculate-the-average-true-range-atr-easy-with-pandas-dataframes/ maybe it will help you

Comment: or maybe this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40256338/calculating-average-true-range-atr-on-ohlc-data-with-python

Comment: Thanks. I actually have already calculated the ATR successfully but I am more in a quest to look for a more elegant and direct way to do it with DF. My question is more like if there is some kind of magical max() function that can work with DF and help create df column in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Following your approach:

```
np.max( ((df['High']-df['Low']).values, np.abs(df['High']-df['Close'].shift()), np.abs(df['Low']-df['Close'].shift())) , axis=0)
```

A function can be this (no pandas copy warning):

```
def ATR(data: pd.DataFrame, window=14, use_nan=True) -> pd.Series:
    df_ = data.copy(deep=True)

    df_.loc[:, 'H_L'] = df_['High'] - df_['Low']
    df_.loc[:, 'H_Cp'] = abs(df_['High'] - df_['Close'].shift(1))
    df_.loc[:, 'L_Cp'] = abs(df_['Low'] - df_['Close'].shift(1))
    df_.loc[:, 'TR'] = df_[["H_L", "H_Cp", "L_Cp"]].max(axis=1)
    df_.loc[:, 'ATR'] = df_['TR'].rolling(window).mean()

    for i in range(window, len(df_)):
        df_.iloc[i, df_.columns.get_loc('ATR')] = (((df_.iloc[i - 1, df_.columns.get_loc('ATR')]) * (window - 1)) + df_.iloc[
            i, df_.columns.get_loc('TR')]) / window

    if use_nan:
        df_.iloc[:window, df_.columns.get_loc('ATR')] = np.nan

    return df_['ATR']
```